# Posterior probabilities from function bic.glm in R

Tags: r, model, bayesian, floating-accuracy

I'm looking at the posterior probabilities output from the function "bic.glm" in R, and they only have 3 digits displayed. Moreover, when I try "options(digits = 16)", I STILL only get posterior probabilities with 3 digits. My question has two parts: Is there any way to see more digits of the posterior probabilities? And how many digits of accuracy of the posterior probability does R use when it makes a prediction from a Bayesian model using the "predict" function?

Answer (score 2):

The posterior probabilities are stored with full precision in `$postprob`.

Using [the vignette](https://github.com/hanase/BMA/blob/master/man/predict.bic.glm.Rd) as an example:

```
library(BMA)
data(UScrime, package = "MASS")
f <- formula(log(y) ~  log(M)+So+log(Ed)+log(Po1)+log(Po2)+log(LF)+
                       log(M.F)+ log(Pop)+log(NW)+log(U1)+log(U2)+
                       log(GDP)+log(Ineq)+log(Prob)+log(Time))
glm.out.crime <- bic.glm(f, data = UScrime, glm.family = gaussian()) 

summary(glm.out.crime)
#...                                                                                                
#nVar                                       7           8           7           8           6    
#BIC                                   -108.92725  -108.75890  -108.07840  -107.70043  -107.56949
#post prob                                0.051       0.047       0.033       0.028       0.026  

 glm.out.crime$postprob[1:5]
#[1] 0.05105381 0.04693225 0.03339668 0.02764572 0.02589375
```

Reviewing the [source code](https://github.com/hanase/BMA/blob/master/R/summary.bic.R) shows that they have hard coded in the limit. Perhaps it was due to formatting the output, but perhaps it was for another reason.

From the source of [`predict.bic.glm`](https://github.com/hanase/BMA/blob/master/R/predict.bic.glm.R), we can see the full value is used:

```
predict.bic.glm <-
function(object,newdata,...){
...
pred <- apply(object$postprob * rhs, 2, sum)
...
}
```